# Diago needs a name addition?

Tags: support

So Diago has been doing a great job as the newest mod to SU.  He ruthlessly puts up with endless amounts of non SU questions and promptly closes them.  He sometimes gets unfairly revenge downvotes due to his all powerful mod powers. I gave him the nickname Diago the Douche due to the reaction of some SU users to his calls. I have agreed with 99% of Diago's mod calls so I want to honor him with a name. I thought Diago the Destroyer was a great name also.  What should Diago add to his name? What would make Diago even more awesome?

https://superuser.com/users/3981/diago

Comment: Turn the a 90 degrees left and it sort of looks like a fancy way of writing "Dingo"

Comment: Someday, I might be as cool as Diago.

Comment: @Troggy: No you won't. Give up now and save us all the pain of having to watch you live your live trying to meet our expectations.

Comment: @Troggy: It's not that we don't love you. It's just that we don't love you as much as Diago.

Comment: This is one of those situations where I am entirely unsure about whether I should take it as a compliment or be completely embarrassed. I suspect it would be safer for my own sanity to stick to the first. However, if I log into tomorrow with no MOD powers I know exactly who to blame :|

Comment: The concept of loving anyone as much as Diago is ludicrous.

Comment: @TheTXI What makes you think Diago loves Troggy?

Answer (score 3):

How 'bout just Diablo

Comment: How did you know that was my favorite game?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we should soften then edge, try and make him seem a more 'sympathetic' and 'caring' moderator, and call him

> Diago the Lovable

That way, people will be less likely to downvote him. They'd seem heartless.

Comment: If you're gonna go in that direction, then go all the way: Diago the Rescuer of Orphaned Puppies.

Comment: "Diago the Unicorn Lover"? Although that sounds a little ceapy somehow.

Comment: Hey - I do love ponies to you know. And waffles... Lot's of waffles.

Comment: @Gnovice: Diago the Rescuer of Kittens caught in Trees on Fire, and Beached Whales.

Comment: if he ever releases a CD... "Diago Love"

Answer (score 3):

Diago the Fist of Righteous Fury

Comment: This is for when Diago locks a meta question.

Answer (score 2):

How about "Diago." It's been working just fine so far. Or, if you like, "Diago Diamond." No need to explain that one.

Comment: Why add the dot to the name?

Comment: I see what you did there :)

Answer (score 1):

From his profile:

> When not in front of a computer he spends his time with his family and their collection of animals.

So perhaps:

> Diago Doolittle

Comment: Full disclosure: 4 Dogs and 5 Cats :P

Comment: Yikes!

Comment: Need to off one of the cats, the dogs are outnumbered.

Comment: I have a couch.

Comment: For a while I had Noah's Ark in my home: 2 people, 2 dogs, 2 rabbits, and 2 fish. Now the fish are gone and a little person is on the way.

Comment: @gnovice That wasn't a fair trade.

Comment: My wife reminded me that sadly I got it wrong, we have 5 dogs and 5 cats.

Comment: Actually both the pets counters has been increased by 1 since this entry was posted. 6 each.

Comment: @Diago: Does that number ever decrease or is it like a recursive method out of control?

Answer (score 0):

Diago the Diviner due to his ability to determine the applicability of questions.

Comment: If only you knew....

Comment: You have a magic coin that you flip?

Comment: Sometimes I wish I had...

Answer (score 0):

William the Conqueror

Answer (score 0):

Manfrenjensen

Comment: I am afraid to ask?

Comment: And yet there's a question mark after your comment.

Comment: A reference to the great movie, A Fish Called Wanda.  When the character has to come up with a fake name, under pressure, he quickly answers "Man.fren...jen....sen".  (with dots indicating the amount of pause between each part, as he realizes his name is getting more and more ridiculous.)

Comment: @Joel - I said afraid... Didn't mean I wasn't brave enough to ask.